# Prettier Extension adding double brackets to if statement

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I have my Prettier extension set to make my code prettier on save. It works amazing 99% of the time...

However:

If I type

`If (x = 14) {};`

my prettier extension in VsCode will change it to

`if ((x=14)) {};`

which will cause nothing to work. I have tried everything to fix this. Prettier is great, but this is so annoying, please help ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks suspicious to me that you use single equal sign in the if statement. Are you sure you want to assign a value? Not sure why prettier uses double brackets though. It may be to highlight the unusual.